# Historicity of Euclid. Looking for the references of Euclid in ancient texts that has survived

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, geometry, ancient-greece, euclid

The general consensus is that Euclid was  a real historical figure. Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid concludes on the  hypothesis that Euclid was not a real person,

"*This hypothesis is not well accepted by scholars and there is little evidence in its favor"*.
Recently I came across a paper by C. K. Raju http://ckraju.net/papers/Euclid.pdf. In this paper Raju opines that

"*If one discounts later Arab sources, as Heath does, our belief in the historicity of Euclid rests wholly and solely on a single remark attributed to Proclus. In this remark, Proclus is  not  particularly definite  about  Euclid,  for his  language admittedly shows that he is the  first  to speak of Euclid, and  is proceeding  on speculative inferences  about events some seven  centuries before his time.*"

Same argument is also advanced later in his book "Euclid and Jesus".

If Raju is right then it casts serious doubts about historicity of Euclid given how influential  Euclid's Elements has been in Greek mathematics and culture. I am surprised that no other scholar has taken note of this and has accepted Euclid as real historical figure.

My question : is Raju's above comment correct? Is there no reference of Euclid before Proclus other than later Arabic sources?

Comment: Even the article you linked mentions earlier references to the "author of *Elements*" by Archimedes and others that do not mention Euclid by name, and Pappus's mention of "Euclid" in connection with Apollonius that predates Proclus's. What Raju means is that "biographies" of Euclid (likely fictitious) only appear in Arab sources. The real question is whether textual analysis of *Elements* suggests a single author, named "Euclid" or not, and most scholars believe that it does.

Comment: You can find a more thorough discussion of sources and controversies concerning Euclid in [O'Connor and  Robertson's article on McTutor](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Euclid/).

Comment: Not only Proclus, but also Pappus mentions Euclid. And not only Elements but other books written by him survive: Optics and Phaenomena, are two of them whose authorship was never disputed.